# Javascript, why is my if statement always returning true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm new to learning javascript and I'm trying to make a rock paper scissors game. I'm trying to run an if statement to check if the player has input a valid answer, but it's always returning true.

```
function validThrow(playerThrow){
  if (playerThrow === 'Rock' || 'Paper' || 'Scissors'){
      return true;
  } else{
      return false;
  }
}
```

No matter what playerThrow is it's always returning true. What am I missing here?

Comment: change `(playerThrow === 'Rock' || 'Paper' || 'Scissors')` to `(playerThrow === 'Rock' || playerThrow === 'Paper' || playerThrow === 'Scissors')`

Comment: It's being evaluated as `((playerThrow === 'Rock') || ('Paper') || ('Scissors'))`; the strings `Paper` and `Scissors` are *truthy*.